# Не могу создать проект в netbeans

Tags: java

При создании проекта, просто ничего не происходит. В отладке netbeans вываливаются сообщения, но разобрать я их не могу.
Есть какие-нибудь предложения что может быть?

- [лог1](https://hastebin.com/irayepuhej.coffeescript)
- [лог2](https://hastebin.com/fewulosusi.rb)

Comment: переустановите заново свой `netbeans`

Comment: Переустанавливал, пытался установить версию более позднюю, не помогло.

Comment: У вас 11 `java`. Попробуйте поставить `netbeans 9`